# Circle function solution in integers

Tags: geometry

I there possible to get all solustions of circle function as integer pairs?

I have problem in image proccessing. I need get every pixel on circle from fixed center and and fixed radius. Pixels are describe by integer cordinates.

So basically I need all solustions of this equation with (h, k) is center and r is radius.

```
(x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 = r^2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to draw a circle then you probably want to use something like Bresenham's algorithm using integer arithmetic, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm. This algorithm comes up with a set of approximate solutions that looks good on the screen. If you want just the exact solutions, then you could obtain them by running Bresenham's algorithm and looking for exact solutions close to the approximate solutions it finds (you would need to check the theory to see how far away from the approximate solutions you need to look, it won't be more than one or two pixels).

Comment: I need get pixels values but this algorithm is good enough. Thanks.